# How use dynamic image URl for Image button

Tags: asp.net

I have a Image button on the aspx page that is server side button.

Now I want to get image url for this from my code class. but this is not working.

```
<asp:ImageButton ID="total" runat="server" ImageUrl='<%=myappnamespace.Utility.GetImageURL("chckout_p.png")%>'>
```

Function `GetImageURl` is public in Utility calls and return the full image path.

If I used this for the following then its working fine

```
<img src='<%=myappnamespace.Utility.GetImageURL("chckout_p.png")%>'>
```

So what is wrong with the server side controls.

Comment: Try setting it from code-behind cs file: `myappnamespace.Utility.GetImageURL("chckout_p.png")` and watch out if you get any errors.

Answer (score 4):

You can't use `<%= codeBehindData.Here %>` on server controls. You can use

`<asp:ImageButton ID="total" runat="server" ImageUrl='<%# myappnamespace.Utility.GetImageURL("chckout_p.png") %>'>`

Notice the `<%#`

Then call `Page.DataBind()` or `total.DataBind()` on `Page_Load`